# If a BroadCastReceiver running in a non-default starts a Service, in what process will that Service run?

Tags: android, android-service, android-alarms

Trying to get my mind around how processes work in Android.
Let's say that I have a **PendingService** called FancyService and an Alarm Receiver:

```
<receiver
  android:name=".FancyAlarmReceiver"
  android:process=":remote" />
<service
  android:name=".FancyService"
  android:exported="false" />
```

Notice that the receiver is process=remote, but the service is not.

Now, let's imagine that the AlarmReceiver just kicks off FancyService...

```
public class FancyAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
        Intent i = new Intent(context, MyTestService.class);
        i.setAction(intent.getAction());
        context.startService(i);
    }
}
```

... then in what process will the service run in? The default process, or the :remote process?

Comment: AFAIK, it will be the default process.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here: The service will run on the default thread, not the remote thread.

I just did an experiment, putting Log.i in the onReceive of the AlarmReceiver, and in the onHandleIntent of the FancyService, and looked in the Android Monitor which process the logs appeared in. The FancyService does indeed log on the main, default process even though it's started by the AlarmReceiver from the :remote thread (and that does indeed log on the remote thread).